# How to undo all in Photoshop quickly

Tags: photoshop

What is the **quickest** method to undo all changes back to the source of the history?

Version: 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about reverting to the previous save then just use

```
function revert_it()
{
  var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID( "Rvrt" );
  executeAction( idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

You can also get the number of history states from  the current document

```
var history = app.activeDocument.historyStates.length;
```

You can add revert to a shortcut menu:
[image: Photoshop keyboard shortcuts menu]

Comment: Very cool! But I was talking about something more practical, like some shortcut key.

Comment: Revert isn't a default keyboard shortcut - but you can add your own. Window > Workspace > Keyboard and Shortcuts Menu. Then look under Application Menus > File